# Is it possible to load rdata-file without file type?

Tags: r, load, rdata

I forgot the addition ".rdata" as I saved the data. Here my mistake:

```
save(data, file="Data_01")
```

The object-class is/was a list.

If I try

```
load(file="Data_01")
```

the following error appears:

> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open connection

Is it possible to load the data?

Comment: Yes! Just try `load(file="Data_01")` and you would see...

Comment: stupidly I assigned to an object. What a shame...